# attempt to solve a Bernoulli equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the Bernoulli equation $y'-y\tan x = y^4 \cos x $ by equating the left hand side to 0 and finding the homogeneous solution, however the equation turned out to be too complex and without the ability to isolate x. Any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y' - y\tan(x) = y^4\cos(x)$

divide throughout by $y^4$

$\frac{y'}{y^4} - \frac1{y^3}\tan(x) = \cos(x)$

let $z= \frac{1}{y^3}\implies z' = \frac{-3}{y^4}y'$

$\frac{-z'}{3} -z\tan(x) = \cos(x)$

$z' + 3\tan(x)\,z = -3\cos(x)$

it is now a Linear differential equation

Integrating factor , $I=e^{\int3\tan(x)}=e^{\ln(\sec^3(x))} = \sec^3(x)$

the solution is given by ;

$z\cdot I =\int-3\cos(x)\cdot I\,dx$

integrate and sub back for $z$

Can you proceed further?Ask if you need help.

EDIT:  on how we got $z\cdot I =\int-3\cos(x)\cdot I\,dx$;

we have $z' + 3\tan(x)\,z = -3\cos(x)$

multiply throughout by $\sec^3(x)$

we get ; $z'\cdot\sec^3(x) +3\cdot\tan(x)\cdot\sec^3(x)\cdot z = -3\cos(x)\cdot\sec^3(x)$

recognize that the LHS is a product rule derivative of  $z\cdot\sec^3(x)$

ie $d(z\cdot\sec^3(x)) =(z'\cdot\sec^3(x) +3\cdot\tan(x)\cdot\sec^3(x)\cdot)\,dx z$

therefore  the equation becomes ;

$\big(z\cdot\sec^3(x)\big)' = 3\cos(x)\cdot\sec^3(x)$

integrating on both sides gives us;

$z\cdot I =\int-3\cos(x)\cdot I\,dx$; $\quad$ where $I= \sec^3(x)$

Comment: how did you do the last transition?

Comment: which one? i dont get what you mean

Comment: $z\cdot I =\int-3\cos(x)\cdot I\,dx$

Comment: check my edit , i've added info you asked for

Answer (score 2):

***Another trick***
$$y'-y\tan x = y^4 \cos x$$
$$\cos(x)y'-y\sin x = y^4 \cos^2 x$$
$$(\cos(x)y)' = y^4 \cos^2 x$$
Substitute $z=\cos(x)y$
$$z' = \frac {z^4} {\cos^2 x}$$
It's separable 
$$\frac 1{z^3}  =-3\int  \frac {dx} {\cos^2 x}$$
$$\frac 1{z^3}  =-3\tan x +K$$
$$z^3  =\frac 1 {-3\tan x +K}$$
$$\boxed{y^3(x)  =\frac 1{\cos^2(x)(K\cos(x)-3\sin x)}}$$
$$......$$

Comment: great solution btw

Comment: yw @Bak1139 and thanks ....

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
 Divide both side by $y^4$ to obtain
$$\frac{y'}{y^4}-\frac{\tan x}{y^3}=\cos x,$$
and set $u=\dfrac 1{y^3}$. The equation rewrites as
$$-\frac13 u'-u\sin x=\cos x\iff u'=-3u\tan x-3\cos x,$$
which is a classical linear differential equation.

Comment: its $\tan(x)$ not $\sin(x)$

Comment: Oops! Sorry for the *lapsus calami*. 'Tis fixed.

Comment: much appreciated, happens to all of us